# Tkinter Save dialog with same extension on multiple filters

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog

Is there a way to get which extension filter a file was saved as using `tkinter.filedialog.SaveAs`? For example using Microsoft Paint, you can save something as a 24 bit bitmap or a Monochrome Bitmap, both are bmp files, but they save differently. Is there a way I can determine which one a user chose?

You can do this through Windows I know using the following API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-getfiletypeindex

However, I am not sure if this is exposed in some way. I've looked all over but the docs for Tkinter aren't that great.

Comment: ***... which save filter ...***: `Tkinter` does not support or use any **save filter**. It's up to you to convert to your prefered image type before saving.

Comment: With dialogs you can pass extension filters to the Open or SaveAs dialogs to add supported formats you wish your program to save or open. Such as `filedialog.SaveAs(filetypes=[("24-bit Bitmap", "*.bmp"),("8-bit Bitmap", "*.bmp")]`

Comment: Thats not a `save filter`, it's a list of descriptions with the asocciated file extension. So you need the **description** to decide ...

Comment: Yes, I need it to return which description or index of which filetype was used.

Comment: I'm not aware how to, others might have good suggestions in this regard. You have to "fake" the extension, e.g. `'.bmp8'` and `'.bmp24'`, and replace afterwards with `'.bmp'`. If the user selects a previous saved `'.bmp'` file you have to analyze it if `8-bit` or `24-bit` or inhibit this at all.